# How to use find in linux to output all files in current directory which match multiple criteria in a single line

Tags: linux, find, command

Trying to come out with a 1 line command in linux to output all files in current directory which matches this criteria:

1. the extension “.csv”
2. a filename that includes “b”
3. a filename that ends with “a” (immediately before the file extension)

I'm aware of how to use find when searching for 1 criterion but unable to make it work with multiple criteria, especially in one line.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about programming or software development. See the [the help center](/help/on-topic) for what sort of questions you can ask here. You may be able to ask this question on [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), but be sure to check with their content guidelines before posting.

Comment: @Brian this is a perfectly on topic question on SO.  `find` is an ubiquitous tool to use in shell scripts, there is even a [`find` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/find).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a glob expression with find. In fact, you're looking for file names that have zero or more characters, then a "b", then another sequence of zero or more characters, then an "a" and then the extension ".csv", i.e.:

```
find . -name '*b*a.csv'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need `find`, say you want to loop over the files.  Then you could save the file names in a bash array like this:

```bash
files=(*b*a.csv)

for f in ${files[@]}; do
    echo "$f" # place holder for whatever command you want to run
done
```

However if you really just want to use `find`, the answer by @Mureinik is sufficient.